# I am getting error messages on console while debugging my Application

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting error messages on console while debugging my Application..

```
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Connection timed out
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197):
```

And a popup window saying..

```
Cannot connect to VM
com.sun.jdi.connect.TransportTimeoutException
```

But in case  when i am running it, application is running successfully followed by a message on console..

```
Could not connect to remote UI listening at localhost:60803. Using default UI instead.
```

I looked for solution on this forum and triyed the suggested answers, but it did not work for eg.

```
1. Turning off the firewall
2. Stopping other programs from using required port.
```

Why i am getting this error?
What is the proper solution of this problem?
Please  do share your knowledge with me.

Comment: checkout the answer from this link :
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19776931/4052916

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot connect to VM in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633502/cannot-connect-to-vm-in-eclipse)

Comment: Hi Arun Kumar, I triyed that solution before and it did not work for me.